# <Errno 32 broken pipe> while uploading large file via remote webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

I have to upload large file (more than `1GB` size) using `remote selenium server` but get `urllib.error.URLError <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>` error.

Here is a `python` code including `remote` driver setup which looks like:

```
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Remote

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
remote = Remote(command_executor="http://localhost:9515",
                desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities())
remote.find_element_by_css_selector('input[name="file"]'
                ).send_keys('path/to/file.iso'))
```

Here is a traceback sample error I have:

```
ERROR:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 475, in send_keys
ERROR:     value = self._upload(local_file)
ERROR:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 692, in _upload
ERROR:     return self._execute(Command.UPLOAD_FILE, {'file': content})['value']
ERROR:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 628, in _execute
ERROR:     return self._parent.execute(command, params)
ERROR:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
ERROR:     response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
ERROR:   File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 472, in execute
ERROR:     resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
ERROR:     response = self._open(req, data)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
ERROR:     '_open', req)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
ERROR:     result = func(*args)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in http_open
ERROR:     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
ERROR:   File "/usr/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
ERROR:     raise URLError(err)
ERROR: urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>
```

Please note that files below `70mb` size are uploading successfully but when I try to upload larger files it fails.

I use `python 3.6`, `selenium 3.12.0`, `chromedriver 2.42` and `Chrome 71`. I did try with different selenium, chromedriver and Chrome versions but got the same error.

I suspect that there are some **chromeoptions** that I can use to fix this, but haven't found yet what exactly can help me.

I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `Remote` WebDriver, it tries to transfer a file to be uploaded to a remote host (in your case from `localhost` to `localhost`; however, general logic is from a host where tests are running to a host where a browser is running).

As you upload a large file, a socket on the peer side is closed before the whole file is uploaded. That's why you see `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 32] Broken pipe>`.

**Solution:** you need to disable file transfer by specifying `UselessFileDetector`

```
remote = Remote(
    command_executor="http://localhost:9515",
    desired_capabilities=options.to_capabilities(),
    file_detector=UselessFileDetector()
)
```

Please note that if your browser is located not at `localhost`, you have to care about transferring a file before uploading it with Selenium.

Edit: you can read more about how does Selenium upload files on https://extsoft.pro/selenium-large-files-upload/